# OnBefore Unload is working I guess but I recieve data only 50% of times

Tags: javascript

this is the simplest code I have written and backend there is simple php api which recieves a get paramter and stores it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        test beforeunload
    </title>
</head>
<body>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function httpGetAsync(data){
        theUrl='http://niteshchaudhry.com/ajay/api.php?name='+data;
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET",theUrl, true); 
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function fireAsap(){
        var elem=document.createElement('script');
        elem.src='http://niteshchaudhry.com/ajay/api.php?name='+new Date();
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elem);
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      fireAsap();
      var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
      e.returnValue = dialogText;
      return dialogText;
    };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

problem is I have observed in database which shows me 1 entry after two refresh or unloads irrespective of which function I use fireasap or httpgetAsync. can anyone explain what is wrong or what can be done to get the data every refresh or unload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `navigator.sendBeacon()`, it's designed for exactly this use case.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

The problem with regular requests is that there's no guarantee that the browser actually manages to send the request before the page gets unloaded, it's done on a 'best effort' basis. `navigator.sendBeacon()` tells the browser to perform a request in the background, separately from the actual page instance. These requests are always POST requests so you'll have to change your server end-point to act on POST instead of GET requests.

`navigator.sendBeacon()` is not yet universally supported so you'll need to use a regular request as a fallback solution.

Comment: Thanks very much... But there is no support for beacon in Internet Explorer and Safari . please tell me alternative for those browsers.

Comment: @ajaymishra The fallback for those browsers is to use the regular AJAX request you're already using and live with the fact that there's always a chance the request may not succeed. There's nothing that can be done about that unfortunately, apart from possibly try to make your server more responsive so that the browser is able to establish a connection to the server and get the request sent before the page is forcibly unloaded.